# Can't get a .jsp file to run on Tomcat 7 ubuntu server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, ubuntu

I installed Tomcat 7 on my Ubuntu 12.04 server using `apt-get`.
As I understand it I just need to upload the project directory containing the `.jsp` file and `WEB-INF` directory containing the `web.xml` file.

The base path: `/usr/share/tomcat7-root/default-root/test/`

index.jsp: `/usr/share/tomcat7-root/default-root/test/index.jsp`

web.xml: `/usr/share/tomcat7-root/default-root/test/WEB-INF/web.xml`

The index.jsp file contents:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <% out.println("this is a test"); %>
</body>
```

The web.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I go to

> mydomain:8080/test/index.jsp

I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /test/index.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /test/index.jsp
>
> description The requested resource (/test/index.jsp) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Have I navigated to the correct directory? The Tomcat landing page loads the `its fine!` page with no errors so I'm assuming Tomcat is running properly.

Am I doing something wrong with the web.xml attributes or the file structure?

edit - typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct directory for Tomcat 7 using `apt-get` on Ubuntu server is `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. It's `WEB-INF`, not `WEB_INF` (a dash, not an underscore)
2. Your web applications should go under `webapps` directory.

So, under `/usr/share/tomcat7-root/default-root/webapps`:

1. Create directory `test`
2. Copy jsp file to `test`
3. Under `test` create directory `WEB-INF`
4. Copy web.xml to `WEB-INF`

Comment: 1. That was just a stackoverflow typo, sorry. 2. Apparently that isn't the tomcat7 root. I managed to find it here: `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/` and everything works as expected. Thanks for your attention though.

Comment: In that case, if you want the web app to correspond to `/test`, just create a `test` directory under `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your problem is with your notion of the base bath and your putting web.xml in the wrong place.  If /default-root is the base path, web.xml should go here:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7-root/default-root/WEB_INF/web.xml
```

at the root of the default root web app.

But I think the default web app for tomcat 7 is ROOT not default-root, no?

Once you get that worked out, I think hitting the url:

```
http:localhost:8080/test/index.jsp
```

will then work.

If you want the welcome file to work then you'll need to update web.xml to something like:

```
 <welcome-file>/test/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```